# What is the order of the midpoint rule?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, approximate-integration, simpsons-rule

If the Trapezoidal-Rule has the order $n=1$, and Simpson's has order $n=2$, what is the order $n$ of the midpoint rule?

And if the weights of the Trapeziumrule are ($1/2, 1/2$) and those of the Simpson-Rule are ($1/6, 4/6, 1/6$), what are the weights of the midpoint-rule?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually, simpson has order $3$. The mid-point-rule has order $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The normal Simpson I meant.. Not the composite: I = (b-a)/6 * ( f(a) + 4*f( (a+b)/2 ) + f(b) )  Isn't these 3 datapoints --> n=3-1=2 ?

Comment: I would consider "order" to be the degree of polynomials that are integrated exactly by the formula. The mid-point rule is just $$(b-a)\cdot f(\frac{a+b}{2})$$

Comment: And doesn't that depends on the nr of points used? And could you please confirm, if I am right with order n=2 as I explained it in the last comment?

Comment: Simpson is still exact for degree $3$. Not only the number of nodes is important, also the weights and the positions of the nodes. Gauss-Legendre-formulas achieve order $2n-1$ with $n$ nodes.

Comment: And how to calculate that order? in an example?

Comment: Let $M=(b+a)/2$ and $ D=(b-a)/2.$ Let $J=\frac {(b-a)}{18}(\;5(f(M-D\sqrt {0.6})+8f(M)+5f(M+D\sqrt {0.6})\;).$... If  $f$ is  a polynomial with deg$(f) \leq 5$ then $J=\int_a^b f(x)dx.$

Comment: 2 questions: 1) about the comment before your last one: So simpson's 1/3 and 3/8 are order 3? And Trapezoidal-Rule of order 1, and Boole's-rule?? 2) How to use the order formula you gave for example with a concrete function? 3) Is it valid to calculate any polynomial's order?

Comment: The (composite) Simpson rule has error order 4, the trapezium rule as well as the midpoint rule have error order 2 (alone from the symmetry the error order has to be even). Your sources are either wrong or have a different definition of error order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error of the Midpoint rule is

$Error_m \leq \frac{k(b-a)^3}{24n^2 } = k(b-a)h^2/24$. So it equals to $O(h^2)$, where $k = max|f"|$.

Comment: Thank you sir! You brought it to the point!

Answer (score 0):

The order of the midpoint rule is $n=2$. For examples, you can see [Why does Trapezoidal Rule have potential error greater than Midpoint?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603830/why-does-trapezoidal-rule-have-potential-error-greater-than-midpoint)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Peter says above that's order 1. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think so. I am strongly sure about this result. This result is classical. You can see "Numerical Analysis. NINTH EDITION. Richard L. Burden" or https://openstax.org/details/books/calculus-volume-2 for more information of the result.

Comment: $O(x^2)$ means order 1. And it is intuitively clear because the Midpoint rule is a quadrature method. You can integrate precisely only a linear function (curvature 0) with a quadrature method.