# getting tight bounds on n!

Tags: integration, combinatorics

> Use integration to prove that $$n! = \Theta\left(\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)$$

I managed to prove that $n! \leq en(n/e)^n$, by applying $\ln$ to both sides and integrating on the function $\ln$.
In a similar way, I showed that $n! \geq e(n/e)^n$.

I can't find a way to get a tighter bound.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Check out the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next level of accuracy comes from applying better estimates for the integral. Taking logarithms, we want to estimate $\ln 2+\ln 3+\cdots+\ln n$ by integrals of $\ln x$. Since the logarithm is increasing, left-endpoint Riemann sums tell us that
\begin{align*}\ln 1+\ln 2+\ln 3+\cdots+\ln n &\le \int_1^{n+1}\ln x\, dx = (n+1)\ln(n+1)-(n+1)-1\ln 1+1\\
n! &\le (n+1)^{n+1}\cdot e^{-n}\end{align*}
If we instead integrate from $1$ to $n$ and then add on the $\ln n$ term after that, the estimate improves slightly to $n! \le n^{n+1}\cdot e^{1-n}=en\left(\frac ne\right)^n$.

Right-endpoint Riemann sums tell us that
\begin{align*}\ln 2+\ln 3+\cdots+\ln n &\ge \int_1^{n}\ln x\, dx = n\ln n-n-1\ln 1+1\\
n! &\ge e\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\end{align*}
There's your estimates. So, then, how can we improve this? Well, right and left endpoint Riemann sums are pretty inaccurate. What if we used midpoint and trapezoid rule estimates?

The logarithm is concave, so the trapezoid rule is an underestimate:
\begin{align*}\frac12\ln 1+\ln 2+\ln 3+\cdots+\frac12\ln n &\le \int_1^n \ln x\,dx = n\ln n-n+1\\
\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\cdot n! &\le e\left(\frac ne\right)^n\end{align*}
The midpoint rule, on the other hand, is an overestimate:
\begin{align*}\ln 2+\ln 3+\cdots+\ln n &\ge \int_{3/2}^{n+1/2} \ln x\,dx = (n+\frac12)\ln (n+\frac12)-\frac32\ln\frac32-n+1\\
n! &\ge \left(\frac23\right)^{\frac32}e\sqrt{n+\frac12}\left(\frac{n+\frac12}{e}\right)^n\end{align*}
Writing the two estimates on one line,
$$\left(\frac23\right)^{\frac32}e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\le \left(\frac23\right)^{\frac32}e\sqrt{n+\frac12}\left(\frac{n+\frac12}{e}\right)^n \le n! \le e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$
The leftmost inequality there is the simple estimate $n+\frac12\ge n$.

That's good enough for your purpose. By moving from endpoint Riemann sums to midpoint and trapezoid estimates, we've reduced the error enough to squeeze $n!$ between two different constant multiples of the same function $\sqrt{n}\cdot \left(\frac ne\right)^n$.

There are ways to do better, including pinning down the exact limiting constant multiple, but that requires a somewhat more sophisticated method; we'd have to estimate the error in our approximated integrals with something like a power series.

Comment: Thank you!
I just have one question- how do you know that the midpoint rule is an overestimate in this case?

Comment: The midpoint rule is always an overestimate for the integral of a concave function. It took some searching, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603830/why-does-trapezoidal-rule-have-potential-error-greater-than-midpoint) has an answer with the picture I was looking for to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(n!)=\frac12\log n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac12\big(\log(k)+\log(k+1)\big)\approx\frac12\log n+\int_1^n\log x \,dx\tag{1}\label{1}$$
We are approximating the integral using the trapezoid rule. We just need a good bound on the error in this approximation.

I claim that

> $$
> \left|\frac12\big(\log(k)+\log(k+1)\big)-\int_{k}^{k+1}\log x\,dx\right|\le \frac1{2k^2}
> \tag2\label2$$

Indeed, consider the function
$$
g(t)=\frac12t\big(\log(k)+\log(k+t)\big)-\int_{k}^{k+t}\log x\,dx
$$
You can show that $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, and $g''(t)=\frac{-\tfrac12t}{(k+t)^2}$. By Taylor's theorem, you have
$$
|g(1)|=|\frac12g''(\xi)|=\frac{\xi}{2(k+\xi)^2}\le \frac{1}{2k^2}\qquad\text{ for some }0\le\xi\le1
$$
Finally, $\eqref2$ shows that the error of the approximation in $\eqref1$ is at most
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2k^2}=O(1)
$$
so that
$$
\log(n!)=\frac12\log n+n\log n-n+1+O(1)
$$